# Как получить "правильный" Current Directory и Unit Test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Доброго времени суток!

VS2010. Добавляю `exe` к проекту сборки, ставлю свойство "копировать всегда", затем запускаю его из кода:

```
Process.Start("testfile.exe");
```

При обычном запуске - все нормально, но если пытаюсь запустить из проекта `unit test` - не видит файл. Смотрю на `Environment.CurrentDirectory` - там адрес директории результатов `unit test-ов` (а не папки где собирается проект сборки или `unit test-а`, куда действительно этот файл копируется).

Как получить "правильный" `Current directory` при `unit test`?

Comment: Как вариант добавить данный ехе И к проекту с тестами.

Comment: не помогает. пробовал. Проблема в том, что даже относительно проекта с тестами оно смотрит не в его папку, а в отдельную папку результатов тестов

Comment: Результаты тестов в смысле некая папка Debug? Копировать всегда также установлено И в проекте с тестами для данного ехе ?

Comment: Для результатов тестов студия в папке решения (то есть на одном уровне с папками проектов) создает папку TestResults, а внутри нее подпапки результатов. Current dir оказывается в одной из них

Comment: А вы не пробовали пользоваться абсолютными путями? Все проблемы разом уйдут. Только, конечно, не прописывать константы в коде, а честно найти каталог, в котором лежит программа, и сконструировать полное имя к искомому файлу.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению нет 10-й студии под рукой, но в чём тогда проблема путь собрать относительный? До папки солюшена Вы подняться сможете, соответственно и к требуемому exe достучитесь.

Если не ошибаюсь, кажется Вам это может помочь - [DeploymentItemAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Добавить `"copy always"/"copy if newer"` к файлу в проекте юнит-теста и к тестовому методу добавить атрибут `[DeploymentItem("testfile.exe")]`.
ps. Вроде еще как "enable deployment" в *.testsettings надо установить.

Answer (score 0):

получить полный путь к твой.exe или получить имя директории где твой.exe
попробуй так:

```
using System.IO;

string fileDirName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
```